# Multi Language loosing text style

Tags: javascript, json

I'm developing a website with Multi Language using this code and I got it to work perfectly but I'm having issues when it changes, all the style in the text is lost and the top menu not only looses it's style but it also stops working completely

This is the javascript function that changes the text:

```
(function() {
$.MultiLanguage = function(a, c) {
    var b = this;
    if (c == null) {
        c = null
    }
    return $.getJSON(a, function(g) {
        var f, d, h, e;
        if (c !== null) {
            localStorage.MultiLanguage = c
        } else {
            if (typeof localStorage.MultiLanguage === "undefined") {
                c = localStorage.MultiLanguage = g.config["default"]
            } else {
                c = localStorage.MultiLanguage
            }
        }
        d = g.language[c];
        e = [];
        for (f in d) {
            h = d[f];
            if ($(f).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "title") {
                document.title = h;
                continue
            }
            if (f.length > 0) {
                e.push($(f).html(d[f]))
            } else {
                e.push(void 0)
            }
        }
        return e
    })
}
})
.call(this);
```

The JSON language file is like this:

```
{
"config": {
    "default": "es"
},
"language": {
    "es": {         
        "#ml-home": "HOME",
        "#ml-agencia": "AGENCIA",
        "ml-img-serv":"images/labels/servicios.png",
        "#ml-texto_agencia": "Somos una agencia creativa y multidisciplinaria que busca potenciar a sus clientes. "
    },
    "en": {
        "#ml-home": "HOME",
        "#ml-agencia": "AGENCY",
        "ml-img-serv":"images/labels/agencia.png",      
        "#ml-texto_agencia": "Octagon is a creative and multidisciplinary agency seeking to empower its customers. "
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What says console? Any errors?

Comment: note that JSON's `"ml-img-serv"` is missing either one of `.` or `#` selectors.

Comment: Do you have the jQuery function unminified? And a snipped about how you use / call it?

Comment: `if (c == null) { c = null }` made my day!

Comment: Roko that's a very important one ;-) won't work without it. charma..

Comment: Hi, I got the code from [link](https://github.com/mingchoi/Multi-Language) it isn't mine. @RokoC.Buljan The console doesn't show any errors  and I changed the way the images are switched between languages so `"ml-img-serv"` isn't there anymore

@SimonKraus This is how I use it 

`<button id="btn-esp" onclick="$.MultiLanguage('js/language.json', 'es')" class="btn">Esp</button><span>&nbsp;</span>
<button id="btn-eng" onclick="$.MultiLanguage('js/language.json', 'en')" class="btn">Eng</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it was loosing the style, the function replaces everything in the HTML, even the styles an classes if the ID isn't set correctly. I fixed it and it works properly.